# How to ignore comments when comparing LaTeX files with TextWrangler?

Tags: comments

In developing a text, I obviously go through numbered versions. But, when trying variants of just a sentence or sometimes a paragraph, I just comment out the previous one as I try the next phrasing.

But then, occasionally, I get mixed up as to in which version I made a particular variant and I use TextWrangler to find out the *status quo* of the numbered versions and having to check all the commented out changes makes it a bit tedious.

Not a high priority item though.

--schremmer